# Get files on PHP web service (SOAP)

Tags: php, .net, web-services, soap

I have .Net client that sends files.

How can i use **PHP web service** to get those files and return them after some changes back to client??

I didn't found code to GET those files, maybe someone have a code example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the file data encoded in [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) from the client to your PHP web service, and handle them with the $_FILES superglobal. There is a similar topic here : [PHP SOAP Transfering Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913106/php-soap-transfering-files)